# Tcolorbox Centered Subtitle

Tags: tcolorbox

Is there an option key for aligning subtitles in `tcolorbox`? I do not see it in the package manual. The best I can do is: `\tcbsubtitle{\centering{My centered subtitle}}`. I am looking for a way to define it in `\tbcset` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `subtitle style={halign=center}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{subtitle style={halign=center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My title]
\tcbsubtitle{My subtitle}
Further text.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Unrelated note: `\centering` is not a macro that takes an argument, so it should be used as `{\centering ..}`, not `\centering{..}`.